# How to disable disk writes for shuffle files?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Hi We have spark cluster , during spark job execution , am getting sparkoutofmemory  when writing  intermediate data to `spark.local.dir` location , but when am seeing their is more than double memory for executor unused , so instead of writing to that dir , can we store the data into memory itself ?

Below the exception details

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 134555 in stage 32.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 134555.3 in stage 32.0 (TID 151065, <<some worker node IP>>, executor 318): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/spark/tmp/spark-98331af4-b923-4342-ae3e-93e764b02d4a/executor-a5874092-943d-4b57-b1d0-eab05a3d36c5/blockmgr-17e989d8-4657-4a4e-bc93-ea075cb45f61/0f/temp_shuffle_1f574b0e-617b-46db-a558-9937a911c90a (No space left on device)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.writeSortedFile(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:211)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.closeAndGetSpills(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:419)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.closeAndWriteOutput(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:230)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
```

Below the screen shot of the failing stage

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there's no way to disable disk writes.

`ShuffleMapTask`s have to write intermediate shuffle map output files (*shuffle blocks*) to `spark.local.dir` directory so reducers (of this shuffle stage) can do their job (no pun intended).

You could give External Shuffle Service a try to reduce disk usage (so rather than every executor would manage their own shuffle-related directories they could offload it). You can read about it a bit in [Dynamic Resource Allocation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation).

Comment: i have standalone spark cluster , this is provided by company internally , inside they are not offering this External Shuffle Service ?

Comment: In Spark Standalone cluster, an external shuffle service is run alongside executors on workers. Just turn on `spark.shuffle.service.enabled` while starting up standalone Workers.

Comment: that means it will store in the same cluster worker nodes and we are facing disk space issue in that cluster , so for me this service of no use

Comment: @Bravo Can't think of any other ways to reduce disk usage (except working with the code to use less shuffles and partitions). You may also want to look at `coalesce` and `repartition` (with columns and number of partitions). But they're again just to minimize disk usage not eliminate it completely.